# Existence of dense subsets $G$-invariant.

Tags: group-actions, invariant-theory

Let $G$ be a group that acts on a manifold $X$. It is well know that the orbir space $X/G$ isn't in general a manifold. But how can I prove that there is always a dense open $U \subset X$ that is $G$-invariant?

Comment: Does $\subset$ mean $\subseteq$ or $\subsetneq$ for you?

Comment: The first one... not necessarely stricktly contained

Comment: Then $X$ is a trivial example.

Comment: But I'm looking for a not trivial example

Comment: Thought so. But since you haven't written that in the question body, I could not resist.

Comment: For a nontrivial example, you need some conditions on the action of $G$. For example if $G$ acts transitively, the only $G$-invariant subsets are $\varnothing$ and $X$.

Comment: Did you mean to ask: Find an open dense subset $U$ so that $U/G$ is a manifold? In any case, in addition to Daniel Fischer's example, consider the action of the modular group $PSL(2, Z)$ on $RP^1$. This action is not transitive, but is *topologically transitive*, so you cannot find any proper invariant open subset.